How to insert a char* into std::vector<char>? Fails with cannot convert argument 2 from 'char *' to 'const unsigned __int64'
I want to transfer binary data via socket. My first attempt was with a std::string but it failed probably due to conversion issues.
My current attempt is to create a std::vector<char> but it fails when I try to append the binary data that is stored in a char* buffer.
// way before
std::vector<char> buf;
std::vector<char>::iterator bufPos = buf.begin();
// some insertions that work, using std::string


// reading a part from a file using an internal toolkit that writes into char*    
char *dataBuf = new char[bufLen];
file.read(dataBuf, n); // n = bytes read
bufPos = buf.insert(bufPos, dataBuf, sizeof(dataBuf));
delete dataBuf;

but this fails in Visual Studio 2017 with this error:
1>c:\src\file.cpp(118): error C2664: 'std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<_Ty>>> std::vector<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>::insert(std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<_Ty>>>,std::initializer_list<_Elem>)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'char *' to 'const unsigned __int64'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=char,
1>            _Elem=char
1>        ]
1>c:\src\file.cpp(118): note: There is no context in which this conversion is possible

I've read multiple questions here and articles on the web, according to them this should work.
I am not sure what missing here. How to get this working?

The first thing is that sizeof(dataBuf) give you the size of the pointer, not the length of the dynamic array.

The build error aside, sizeof(dataBuf) will not work as you expect. It will give you the size of the pointer, not whatever memory it might point to. Is there a reason you need to use char* and explicit dynamic allocation? Especially since you seem to have problems with it (delete dataBu is also wrong)?

The correct code is buf.insert(bufPos, dataBuf, dataBuf + bufLen); (and then presumably bufPos += bufLen;). vector::insert does not have the overload you were expecting, see reference.

As for your problem of reading into a vector from a file, there are very nice ways of doing that in one single statement: std::vector<char> buf(std::istream_iterator<char>(file), std::istream_iterator<char>()); There, all done. The whole file inside the vector. And if you don't want thew whole file, use std::copy_n instead.

buf.insert(bufPos, dataBuf, dataBuf+n);

I'd like to see one of these references that say the code should work, because they are clearly wrong (or you have misinterpreted them).

Yes, I made a mistake. buf.insert(bufPos, dataBuf, dataBuf+bufLen) seems to work with a minor issue: it overrides the data that has already been inserted into the vector.

@Apollo That's presumably because you did not increment bufPos as I indicated in my comment.

@Apollo To be clear, because insert may invalidate iterators to the vector you need bufPos = buf.insert(bufPos, dataBuf, dataBuf + bufLen); bufPos += bufLen; or (same thing) bufPos = buf.insert(bufPos, dataBuf, dataBuf + bufLen) + bufLen; The return value from insert is guaranteed to be a valid iterator, but the iterator is still pointing to the same place as it was before you called insert to you also need to increment the iterator by the number of items you have added.

Re: "insert a char*" -- a char* is a pointer. Nothing more. It usually points at the first element of an array of char, and it's the array that you want to insert, not the pointer.
